# Beginner to sqlite - Can't create a database

Tags: sqlite

So I'm very new to this and I'm trying to create a database using sqlite (with the instructions in their documentation). I get this error after the first line of code. Does anyone know what's going on?

I'm using terminal on OS X Lion.

```
$ sqlite3 ex1.db
SQLite version 3.7.5
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> create table tb11(one varchar(10), two smallint);
Error: unable to open database "ex1.db": unable to open database file
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most obvious thing would be lack of permission to write to your current working directory. This is the exact error message I get in that case (too bad it doesn't bother to include useful information like "permission denied")

If you have access to `strace`, then you can confirm like this:

```
$ strace -f sqlite3 ex1.db 'create table tb11(one varchar(10), two smallint);' 2>&1 | grep ex1.db
execve("/usr/bin/sqlite3", ["sqlite3", "ex1.db", "create table tb11(one varchar(10"...], [/* 58 vars */]) = 0
access("ex1.db", F_OK)                  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/tmp/d/ex1.db", 0x7fffb18fc690)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/tmp/d/ex1.db", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0644) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
open("/tmp/d/ex1.db", O_RDONLY)         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "Error: unable to open database \""..., 70Error: unable to open database "ex1.db": unable to open database file
```

Notice the result of `open` is `EACCESS (Permission denied)`.

Comment: @derobert Thanks, I think I figured it out. I just changed the directory I was in and I'm able to create the database, so it was most probably lack of permission.

Answer (score 0):

Check write permissions, and make sure you follow each step carefully in the tutorial:

http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have permissions to the directory in which you are running this command.
You need to have write permissions where sqlite will create a file for your database.

If you don't have permissions, try changing permissions by chmod command.
You could also change to a directory where your user profile has write permissions.

I tried to create database in /usr/bin and it failed because it had no write permissions for my profile. But when i moved to my home directory ($HOME) , then i was able to create the database.